AABB Collision Doesn't Line Up
I've been following this for AABB collisions and translated it to 3D. However, I've found that the collision math doesn't work, and two boxes defined like this:
    struct AABB player = {
        .position = {10, 7, 10},
        .half = {1.5, 1.5, 1.5} // 3^3 box
    };

    struct AABB box = {
        .position = {10, 5, 10},
        .half = {0.5, 0.5, 0.5} // 1^3 box
    };

are said to not be colliding, when obviously, a 3x3x3 player should collide with a 1x1x1 box when the player is only 2 units above the other box. You can run and see the code here, where the result is not expected: https://godbolt.org/z/o9fMWodvT
Any idea why the collision detection isn't working properly would be greatly appreciated.

The boxes are touching, not colliding.

@EricPostpischil as you can see here from this source I followed, https://github.com/noonat/intersect/blob/master/src/intersect.ts#L165, this is exactly how it should be handled.

That will say any objects centered on the same point do not collide (if they have any width at all) I'm not sure how you came to that conclusion. If they are on the same point the formula simplifies to px = (box.half.x + aabb.half.x) - 0 which is obviously not negative.

Well then how would the updated collision math work, assuming that the resource is wrong?

The collision math is fine. As I said in my first comment, the boxes just aren't colliding, they are touching exactly. Change the <= 0 conditions to < 0 to get a hit in this case.

My mistake, I mixed up lines of code. Nonetheless, did you debug this at all? You should have either stepped through it in a debugger or printed the values of variables at critical points to see what decision the program was making. Debugging questions on Stack Overflow should be reduced to a [mre], and that should be included in the question directly, not as a link to an external site. Reducing this problem to an [mre] would include figuring out exactly which branch was responsible for deciding there was no hit.
